# my django project static files can not be load with option debug=false

Tags: python, django

It is very strange that my django website (setup on a linux server with django 1.3) can be visit correctly with DEBUG = True. But when I changed the option to DEBUG = False the static content won't load (css files and images can not be found)

Here's related options i got in my setting.py:

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_ROOT = ''
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/home/ubuntu/ls_website/static/",)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Anybody have any idea? If the version is too low, I would wait a while for 1.5 release.

Comment: it's because your path is hard coded, so if your viewing it throught windows that's different path. My advice make your path available to all, don't hard code it

Comment: I found my problem is not related to platform but the option DEBUG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found when debug=False, django won't load static files automatically. Options are set static path in urls.py or serve static files with apache.
People said set static path in urls.py is slower than serve static files with apache. Don't know why though...

Comment: Because django said it is not a professional web engine (only for dev). static files better served in professional web engine in production env.

Answer (score 1):

Staticfiles doesn't do anything when DEBUG=False.  You need to serve those files with apache.  Staticfiles has the ability to collect the files to one spot for you to make it easy, then you use some apache magic (assuming here since you didn't specify) to have apache intercept those requests and serve the static files for you.

```
    Alias /robots.txt  /home/username/Python/project/site_media/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/username/Python/project/site_media/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/     /home/username/Python/project/site_media/static/
```

I don't remember if it is buildstatic, build_static, collectstatic or collect_static to copy those files from your development stop to your deployment spot, but these variables control how staticfiles does its magic

```
# Absolute path to the directory that holds static files like app media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/apps/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static")

# URL that handles the static files like app media.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Additional directories which hold static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media"),
]
```

This assumes your static files are in the **static** folder of your project, and you want to serve them from the **site_media** folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also move between Windows and Linux for development. To get around the problem of absolute paths in settings.py, I use this function:

```
def map_path(directory_name):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
        '../' + directory_name).replace('\\', '/')
```

Which you can implement in this fashion:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    map_path('static'),
)
```

This function is tailored for Django 1.4.x. You'll need to modify it slightly for Django 1.3.x. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Maybe you mis-understood my question. I am not moving my server from Linux to Windows. My server is on Linux, which is not changed. So i think i don't need to use os.path.dirname(__file__).
What changes from Linux to windows is web browser.

Comment: No problem. If you're referring to the staticfiles app's ability to serve static files in development, that's entirely based on the DEBUG setting. If DEBUG = True, staticfiles will serve those files automatically, otherwise you will need to have Apache, etc, serve those files.